# Why is this JSON "invalid?"

Tags: javascript, json, validation, syntax-error, jsonlint

This JSON passes [jsonlint](http://www.jsonlint.com) validation. Yet Firefox and Chrome reject it:

```
{
    "messages": [
        {
            "subject": "One"
        },
        {
            "subject": "Two"
        },
        {
            "subject": "Three"
        }
    ],
    "totalResults": 10
}
```

The error message is "invalid label" on "messages."

This is how it is being loaded:

```
var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    model: 'MyModel',
    autoLoad: true,
    pageSize: 3,
    proxy: {
        type: 'jsonp',
        url: 'http://localhost:8080/document-viewer-1.0/testdata.json',
        reader: {
            root: 'messages',
            totalProperty: 'totalResults'
        }
    }
});
```

**Answer**:

It was my own stupid mistake. I didn't put the JSONP callback name around the JSON file structure.

Comment: The JSON is valid.  http://jsonlint.com

Answer (score 8):

What you have is valid JSON,  but it's not valid JSON **P**

You need to change

```
type: 'jsonp',
```

to

```
type: 'json',
```